# Proving that $O(n)$ is compact

Tags: matrices, analysis, compactness, orthogonality

Let $O(n)$ denote the group of orthogonal matrices under multiplication. We want to show that this is set is compact.

To show $O(n)$ is compact, we can use Heine-Borel and show that it is closed and bounded. I think I proved the boundedness of $O(n)$, so that's not a problem for now. To prove that it is closed, I saw a proof in where writing (for an orthogonal matrix denoted as $U=(u_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{n}$):

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{ij}u_{ik}=\begin{cases} 1 &\mbox{if } j = k\\ 0 &\mbox{if } j \neq k \end{cases}$

Which can be done as $U^{T}U=I$, so it follows that $O(n)$ is a closed subset of $M(n,n,\mathbb{R})$ (set of $n \times n$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}$). However, how would the result above (rewriting $U^{T}U=I$) imply that the set is closed? I'm not sure if I get the main idea.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: $U^TU$ is a continuous function of $U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $X \mapsto X^tX$ is a continuous function from the space of all $n \times n$ matrices to itself. Therefore the inverse image of the closed set $\{I\}$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I thought as well (and did), but can the above steps shown be used to as well prove that the set is closed? (or that the function is continuous?). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The step shows that the set of orthogonal matrices is closed.